# C++ _popen() / system() running consecutive commands on windows

Tags: c++, windows, system, popen

I am working on a remote command prompt for a server of mine. I am running into an issue with both `_popen()` and `system()` because once the command executes and the process will close/start a new instance (losing variables like active directory). I want to be able to run code like.

```
_popen("cd ..","r");
_popen("cd windwos","r");
_popen("dir","r");
```

I will also need a method of getting the pointed for the output text (this is why I started using `_popen()`. I am not sure if it is possible with `_popen()`, or I need to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

For changing directory, you will need to do that in the current process. So you probably need a piece of code roughly like this:

```
if (cmd == "cd" || cmd == "chdir")
{
   chdir(argv[1]); 
}
```

The reason that running "cd" inside `popen` doesn't work is that it inly changes the directory in the CURRENT process. Making it change for the parent process would cause all manner of problems.

Of course, you may need to intercept a few other things, for example "set" (for environment variables), perhaps.

Comment: Changing directories is not the main issue. I am wanting to keep the instance of command prompt so I could continue executing commands even if I open other applications in command prompt.

Comment: That will not be easy - I don't think windows has "Pseudo-Terminals", like Linux/Unix systems (if that was the case, it's pretty simple). Have you considered not doing this, and just using for example an existing `sshd` (Secure Shell Daemon) on your remote machine, and for example `putty` (SSH client, Secure Shell Client) on the local machine?

Comment: I don't see why Windows would even need "pseudo-terminals". (But personally I consider the Unix terminal model to be a complete mess, which should have been scrapped  together with the teletypes it was intended for). Anyway, on Windows you'd just spawn a CMD.EXE child process and keep its input handle open in the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single command: `dir ..\windows\`. Or more verbose: `cd .. && cd windows && dir`